# Выравнивание текста относительно иконки

Tags: html, css, float, blocks

Не могу выровнять текст, чтобы был как на рисунке. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать? Возможно не надо было делать новый класс, а расставлять всё в одном?

```css
.icon-block{
 width: 370px;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 28px;
}

.icons:nth-child(1){
 padding-left: 130px;
}

.icons-text{
 margin-top: -60px;
 margin-left: 70px;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
}

.icons-text span{
 font-weight: 300px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-block">
     <div class="icons">
      <img src="img/Hourglass.png" alt="">
      <div class="icons-text">
       До центра 5 минут на машине <span>или общ. транспорте</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Встречайте [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) - прекрасный инструмент для свякого рода выравниваний =)

```css
.icons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-block">
  <div class="icons">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQpsd9jAaaHm-OMhNFoNetA54LuMWat4Hz5FneDXfUsG4cYJhBe" alt="картинко" style="height:150px;border:1px solid #888">
    <div class="icons-text">
      До центра 5 минут на машине <br/><span>или общ. транспорте</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flag {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: green;
}

.flag::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flag">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ширину блока увеличить:

```
.icon-block{
width: 445px;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.icon-block{
 width: 370px;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 28px;
}

.icons {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.icons-text{
 margin-left: 20px;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000;
}

.icons-text span{
 font-weight: 300px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-block">
 <div class="icons">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/60/60" alt="">
  <div class="icons-text">
       До центра 5 минут на машине <span>или общ. транспорте</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```